# WordPress - custom excerpt printing <a> text inside a <p> when it shouldn't

Tags: php, wordpress

I may need to work on the titling of this.

I have a function:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
        if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
            array_pop($excerpt);
            $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
          } else {
            $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
          } 
        $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
        return $excerpt;
    }
```

And I'm calling it with `<?php echo excerpt(25);?>`. This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="recent-meta-excerpt">
                            <?php echo excerpt(25);?>
                            <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
```

It's outputting like this:

```
<div class="recent-meta-excerpt">
   <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout....                           <a class="read-more" href="http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/no-featured-image/">Read More <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
   </p>
</div>
```

But I don't want the `<a>` inside. When I'm calling the excerpt the `<a>` isn't even inside so I'm not sure how it's being wrapped in a `<p>`.

Comment: This is odd. I tested it on Twenty sixteen and I see no `p` tags wrapped around. Do you have some plugin, or did you change any `wpautop` functionality?

Comment: As a workaround try wrapping your excerpt explicitly in a `div` or a `p`...

Comment: If I put it in a `<p>` around it, an empty one will appear above the excerpt. I don't think I have a plugin to mess with the `wpautop`.